# What means "Observer reaction functions should not change model" using a nested ng-repeat?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Here's a simplified version of the code where I get an error that is logged even if the generated HTML looks good. What does this exception means ? Why do I get it ?

*index.html* :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div ng-app main>
  <div ng-repeat="a in ctrl.listOfA">
    <strong>{{ a }}</strong>
    <div ng-repeat="b in ctrl.listOfB(a)">
      {{ b }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

*main.dart* :

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';  /* 0.9.10 */

@NgController(selector: '[main]', publishAs: 'ctrl')
class MainController {
  final listOfA = new List.generate(2, (i) => 'a$i');
  listOfB(a) => new List.generate(2, (i) => 'b$i').map((e) => '$a-$e');
}

void main() {
  ngBootstrap(module: new Module()
    ..type(MainController)
  );
}
```

The logged error :

```
Observer reaction functions should not change model. 
These watch changes were detected: ctrl.listOfB(a): (a0-b0, a0-b1) <= (a0-b0, a0-b1); ctrl.listOfB(a): (a1-b0, a1-b1) <= (a1-b0, a1-b1)
These observe changes were detected: 

STACKTRACE:
#0      RootScope.flush.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/scope.dart:554:11)
#1      RootScope.flush (package:angular/core/scope.dart:560:9)
#2      RootScope.flush (package:angular/core/scope.dart:561:7)
#3      RootScope.flush (package:angular/core/scope.dart:561:7)
#4      apply (package:angular/core/scope.dart:262:18)
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:710)
#6      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:711)
#7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:711)
#8      _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:440)
#9      NgZone._finishTurn (package:angular/core/zone.dart:96:21)
#10     NgZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:61:43)
#11     _onRun (package:angular/core/zone.dart:66:15)
#12     _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:440)
#13     _CustomizedZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:650)
#14     NgZone.run (package:angular/core/zone.dart:148:35)
#15     ngBootstrap (package:angular/bootstrap.dart:92:18)
#16     main (http://127.0.0.1:3030/xxxx/web/test/main.dart:13:14)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular only supports pure functions in expressions. I guess this started with 0.9.10 because there already was a similar question recently where it stopped working after the update.

```dart
ctrl.listOfB(a)
```

should always return the same result for the same argument,

or even if the result is the same, the cause could be that `ctrl.listOfB(a)` always returns a new instance of the same result. Angular 0.9.10 doesn't like this either.

It repeatedly evaluates the expression and if it receives a new result each time it throws.

I think the solution is to cache the results and return from the cache if already available.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Günter ! By caching the result of `ctrl.listOfB(a)` the error does not appear anymore. BTW What do you mean by _pure functions_ ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function (as explained 'should always return the same result for the same argument')