# Observer reaction functions should not change model

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Chapter_06 in AngularDart example
when I run it in Dartium, there are some error:

```
Observer reaction functions should not change model.
These watch changes were detected: ctrl.allRecipes: [Instance of 'Recipe', Instance of 'Recipe']
cmp.categories: [Appetizers, Salads, Soups, Main Dishes, Side Dishes, Desserts] 
<= [Appetizers, Salads, Soups, Main Dishes, Side Dishes, Desserts]
These observe changes were detected:

STACKTRACE:
#0      RootScope.flush.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/scope.dart:554:11)
#1      RootScope.flush (package:angular/core/scope.dart:560:9)
#2      RootScope.flush (package:angular/core/scope.dart:561:7)
#3      RootScope.flush (package:angular/core/scope.dart:561:7)
#4      apply (package:angular/core/scope.dart:262:18)
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:710)
#6      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:711)
#7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:711)
#8      _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:440)
#9      NgZone._finishTurn (package:angular/core/zone.dart:96:21)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What means "Observer reaction functions should not change model" using a nested ng-repeat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637485/what-means-observer-reaction-functions-should-not-change-model-using-a-nested)

Comment: Did you customize the code of the tutorial or is it unmodified? There were changes in Angular recently that disallow certain constructs and the tutorial might not be up-to-date. If the code is unmodified and you are using the most recent Dart version please create an in the angular.dart.tutorial GitHub repository.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, the code is unmodified and using the lastest Dart. I think that code not include pure function, you can check it, Thank you.