# Disable strict/checked mode in Dart Angular

Tags: dart, webstorm, angular-dart, dartium

I'm using WebStorm and Dart Angular and I'm having trouble with some kind of strict or checked mode.

Whenever I run the application using default WebStorm configuration, I get failed assertions `Observer reaction functions should not change model.`, `boolean expression must not be null` and `type 'SubListIterable' is not a subtype of type 'List<Tag>'`.

As far as I understand, this is happening because Dart VM is running in checked mode and I would like to turn it off. Dartium is launched with options `--no-sandbox --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end`, if it is important.

When I open the page in Chrome, everything's fine but of course I can't debug.

EDIT: 1st error is apparently not related to checked mode. Here is a snippet of what I try to achieve:

```
List get getCorrectTags {
  if(this.allowTags)
    return this.tags.map((t) => t.name).toList();
  else
    return this.contentTags;
}
```

Current solution is like this:

```
bool invalidateCorrectTags = false;
List correctTags = [];
List get getCorrectTags {

  if (this.invalidateCorrectTags) {
    this.invalidateCorrectTags = false;
    if(this.allowTags)
      this.correctTags  = this.tags.map((t) => t.name).toList();
    else
      this.correctTags = this.contentTags;
  }

  return this.correctTags;
}
```

and I have to set `invalidateCorrectTags` to `true` in each setter, where changes in said setter will affect result of getCorrectTags. Is there a better of way of doing it?

Comment: Checked mode is to prevent potential bugs. What about fixing the issues instead? The first error (Observer reaction ...) is not related to checked mode anyway AFAIK. The errors are quite easy to fix.

Comment: How can I correct first error? I understand last 2 (type mismatch) and fixed them already but 1st one requires cashing and invaliding of these cashes in model getters.

Comment: Can you please post the code. I don't know how to fix what I can't see ;-)

Comment: "Observer reaction functions" sounds like Angular.Dart 1.x, but you added the `angular2` tag. What Angular version are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637485/what-means-observer-reaction-functions-should-not-change-model-using-a-nested

Comment: Solution proposed in this link is same thing as I did, right?

Comment: I don't think so. This line `this.correctTags  = this.tags.map((t) => t.name).toList();` results in a new object (`List`) be assigned to `correctTags`.  It's not clear how you use it. If you bind to `correctTags` then it should work fine. If you bind to `getCorrectTags` then not.

Comment: You can try `assert(identical(getCorrectTags(), getCorrectTags()));`. If you don't get an error for this code, then you did it right (use instead of `getCorrectTags()` what you bind to in the view).

Answer (score 2):

The option to disable checked mode was removed recently from WebStorm

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24466

A mentioned workaround is to add

```
<entry key="DART_FLAGS" value="--checked" />
```

to  `[configuration]/options/web-browsers.xml`